# Fit poster to wood

Tags: posters

I'm making a arcade style joystick and I'm wanting a poster on the top panel to make it look good.

How can I do this bearing in mind it will get a lot of wear?

Comment: Welcome to A&C! Can you include some more details to help your question get more focused answers: what's the base material of the joystick -- wood? what's your budget like? are you planning to print a design or hand-create artwork?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to think about two pieces of material:

1. The poster that you will print, and
2. a clear protective layer over top of it.

This protective layer may be printed or fused directly on top of the poster, or it may be a separate sheet which is mounted overtop.

If you were going to mount it as an overlay without bonding it to the poster, then you will need to be sure that it is rigid and does not raise or move during play. I think that this is unlikely, and you Will need to fuse it altogether with a glue, but I wanted to mention the option.

The best way to get the fusion of poster and protective layer is to have it printed by a professional service. They will have access to clear plastic / coatings which are bonded with heat or UV curing.  I.E. a process that you would spend more time and effort to source and execute on your own, vs. using a service.

When adhering the poster to the wood backing, be sure first to test your bonding agent by using some of the poster-material extra and spare wood from your main board.  Watch for bleed-though and other alterations.  To perform the best test, be sure to print your poster with a wide bleed area, and file the unused space with graphic overprints, so that you have complex images/color that will demonstrate possible damage from adhesives.